# Anyone could change this for me? Rating system css from "high to low" to "low to high"

Tags: html, css, rating, rating-system

currently I want to use this rating system from http://codepen.io/JaxoDI/pen/DtsdH . But currently it works when you hover from right to left. Feel free to try it out in the link given. But I wanted to have a rating system which hovers from left to right.

I do not have any basic knowledge on css. Any answers would be very appreciated. Thank you.

```
&:hover {
    //Apply styles to this and all subsequent radio buttons
    /*  This is the reason why it has to go from high-to-low
        In CSS4, we should be able to use !, which will select
        up the DOM (select elements _before_ this one)  */
    &:before, ~:before {
      transition:none;
      background:#2ecc71;
      box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The CSS is not what dictates the order of the radio buttons.  Look at the HTML, not the CSS.

Comment: Samuel, the CSS by design has to go right from left with the rating system. You cannot go left to right using this method. Either remake it completely with a different method or live with it being right to left.

Comment: Alright. Thanks  . I've to find another rating system then. Would love to redesign but i do not have any knowledge of it and I need it done by Monday.

Comment: You could reverse engineer this: http://jsfiddle.net/y9zeLr1n/

Comment: Will have a look at that later. Thanks ! @Drakes

Answer (score 0):

You could float the inputs right to change their direction.

```
input[type="radio"].rating {
    float: right;
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qbagxm